# php document url with parameters in url does not work

Tags: php, html, url, webserver

I´ve got an url like this `www.example.com/v=12345`. This will go to my index.php site on my webserver and the variable 'v' is used to do some javascript stuff, which works fine.

Now i want to link to the document 'newsite.php" like this or similar: `www.example.com/newsite.php/v=12345`. This does not work since the css does not work anymore and i don't know why.. If i do it like `www.example.com/newsite.phpv=12345` , the variable is read correctly but it opens the index.php again.. How can i do this correctly?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Re-read you question please and make sure you haven't missed anything? Some parts of your codes look wrong: `www.example.com/newsite.phpv=12345`

Comment: why you are not passing this as a parameter like this: www.example.com?v=12345

Comment: okay i am posting an answer. if it work then you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass php variable in url as parameter like this:

```
www.example.com?v=12345
```

and in your php just get this value by:

```
$_GET['v']
```

It should solve your problems :)

Comment: Works with js as well ty.

Answer (score 1):

Variables need the seperator ? between url and variable. And if you have more Variables, the variables are seperated with a &

Example:

```
www.domain.com/?v=123
www.domain.com/script.php?v=123

www.domain.com/?v=123&y=456
```

And every variable will be available via $_GET[]

```
$_GET['v']
$_GET['y']
```